# Unable to get heroku started on cloud9 ide

Tags: ruby, heroku, command-line, cloud9

I am running the command - `curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

Which throws the following error -

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1232  100  1232    0     0   5133      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5112
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
+ dpkg -s apt-transport-https
+ echo ''
sh: line 4: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list: No such file or directory
```

I also ran `sudo snap install --classic heroku` which returned `sudo: snap: command not found`.

Then I ran `sudo apt install snapd` which returned the following -

```
apt: invalid flag: install
Usage: apt <apt and javac options> <source files>
where apt options include:
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processor factories
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processor factories
  -d <path>                  Specify where to place processor and javac generated class files
  -s <path>                  Specify where to place processor generated source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options; use javac -help for more options
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  -A[key[=value]]            Options to pass to annotation processors
  -nocompile                 Do not compile source files to class files
  -print                     Print out textual representation of specified types
  -factorypath <path>        Specify where to find annotation processor factories
  -factory <class>           Name of AnnotationProcessorFactory to use; bypasses default discovery process
See javac -help for information on javac options.


warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
```

Finally, I ran `wget 0- wget https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` which returned

```
--2020-09-10 18:15:53--  http://0-/
Resolving 0- (0-)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘0-’
--2020-09-10 18:15:54--  http://wget/
Resolving wget (wget)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘wget’
--2020-09-10 18:15:54--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 54.164.74.108, 107.23.162.152, 34.194.108.77, ...
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|54.164.74.108|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 719 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘install-ubuntu.sh’

install-ubuntu.sh                 100%[=============================================================>]     719  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-09-10 18:15:54 (105 MB/s) - ‘install-ubuntu.sh’ saved [719/719]

FINISHED --2020-09-10 18:15:54--
Total wall clock time: 0.4s
Downloaded: 1 files, 719 in 0s (105 MB/s)
```

So then, I ran `bash install-ubuntu.sh` which returned -

```
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
sh: line 3: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list: No such file or directory
sh: line 6: apt-key: command not found
--2020-09-10 18:16:51--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 54.145.36.98, 54.164.74.108, 107.23.162.152, ...
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|54.145.36.98|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1737 (1.7K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                   0%[                                                              ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      


Cannot write to ‘-’ (Success).
sh: line 9: apt-get: command not found
sh: line 12: apt-get: command not found
```

I am taking an online course on Upskill and am on video #125. Please advise how to progress.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I have a gist I use specifically for setting up rails on Cloud9 (though I haven't updated it for Rails 6 yet). Recommend you read through it twice before you try to do it. You may need to go out of order in some cases, as exact approach depends on if you are cloning an existing repo or building a new app.

https://gist.github.com/MyklClason/791d6b14606bc56e72eba2995aab8e76

You probably don't need `snap`.

Also useful bash aliases for Cloud9:
https://gist.github.com/MyklClason/d71a39ace28b9ec9f0ad

As for your actual issue. Heroku toolbelt is obsolete, use this instead:

`wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

Also it's often best to just look online and check how to install the heroku cli (or anything really) for your OS using the offical documentation. Though that may not work for older setup. However, heroku is something where you basically have to use the newest version otherwise you are going to run into problems.

Comment: thanks! Will reference the gist as per requirement. I used the command you suggested and received the following response                                                     
          "This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
+ dpkg -s apt-transport-https
+ echo ''
sh: line 4: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list: No such file or directory"                  I have tried updating the superuser but am unsure what password is to be provided. Please let me know if you have any tips for the same. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: run `sudo wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`? Interesting issue. You might be better off asking a question for that issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't figure this out...

```
nvm i v8
```

Followed by...

```
npm install -g heroku
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).